# How to get entity object in buildform formbase?

Tags: forms, commerce, 9

I've the following in my routing.yml

```
project.product_elasticsearch:
  path: '/product/{commerce_product}/elasticsearch'
  defaults:
    _form: '\Drupal\mymodule\Form\ProductElasticsearchForm'
    _title: 'Elasticsearch'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'access content'
  options:
    _admin_route: TRUE
```

and in class `ProductElasticsearchForm` `buildForm()` looks as below,

```
public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state, ProductInterface $commerce_product = NULL) {
}
```

`$commerce_product` is received as a string instead of an object.

I get the following PHP error.

TypeError: Drupal\mymodule\Form\ProductElasticsearchForm::buildForm(): Argument #3 ($commerce_product) must be of type ?Drupal\commerce_product\Entity\ProductInterface, string given in Drupal\mymodule\Form\ProductElasticsearchForm->buildForm() (line 25 of modules/custom/mymodule/src/Form/ProductElasticsearchForm.php).

Would like to know if I'm missing anything. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare type type of object that `{commerce_product}` is in your routing definition:

```yaml
project.product_elasticsearch:
  path: '/product/{commerce_product}/elasticsearch'
  defaults:
    _form: '\Drupal\mymodule\Form\ProductElasticsearchForm'
    _title: 'Elasticsearch'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'access content'
  options:
    _admin_route: TRUE
    # Add this section to define what type of object {commerce_prodcuct} is:
    parameters:
      commerce_product:
        type: entity:commerce_product
```

You'll need to clear your registry after this.

Comment: Thanks @Jaypan. For some reason, drush cc as well is not reflecting the menu changes. Not sure how to make the registry clear in Drupal 8.

Comment: In Drupal 8+ it's `drush cr`.